# How to add new Users into SQL server database through JAVA GUI

Tags: java, sql, user-interface

I am creating a GUI through Eclipse and am using Java; and the application connects to an SQL server database. I managed to add new users directly using Microsoft SQL server with their respective securables or restrictions.

However, I would like to add new users through the GUI itself and be able to determine which table they can access. Or at least just add new users and then ill figure out how to determine which table they can access. Im running into a problem converting the SQL code into Java, ( I am new to all this after all).

Thank you in advance,

Following is the SQL Code I found used in SQL Server to add new login and then a new User, the idea is to replace "NewAdminName" and "ABCD" with the actual user input directly from the GUI:

```
CREATE LOGIN NewAdminName WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCD'
GO

Use BEPAWI;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'NewAdminName')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [NewAdminName] FOR LOGIN [NewAdminName]
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'NewAdminName'
END;
```

Following is the JAVA code Im am currently working on with Eclipse:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Enter");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {

                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";
                    username = UsernametextField.getText().trim();
                    password = PasswordtextField.getText().trim();

                    if (username.equals("")|| password.equals(""))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," name or password is wrong","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(AdminMenu.DATABASE_URL, AdminMenu.UserName, AdminMenu.Password);
                        statement = connection.createStatement();


                        resultSetInt = statement.executeUpdate("CREATE LOGIN '"+username+"' WITH PASSWORD = ''"+password+"'' GO USE BEPAWI GO IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''"+username+"'') BEGIN CREATE USER ['"+username+"'] FOR LOGIN ['"+username+"']  EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N''"+username+"'' END;) VALUES('"+username+"', '"+password+"');");
                        System.out.println(resultSetInt);

System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");

                        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");


String SMessage = "Record added for "+username;

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,SMessage,"Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        //close connection
                        ((java.sql.Connection)connection).close();
                    }

                    }

                catch (SQLException se) 
                {
                    //handle errors for JDBC
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception a) //catch block
                {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

I believe my problem is this line of code:

```
resultSetInt = statement.executeUpdate("CREATE LOGIN '"+username+"' WITH PASSWORD = ''"+password+"'' GO USE BEPAWI GO IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''"+username+"'') BEGIN CREATE USER ['"+username+"'] FOR LOGIN ['"+username+"']  EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N''"+username+"'' END;) VALUES('"+username+"', '"+password+"');");
```

Maybe I have to add all the columns from the SQL table? such as the 
sys.database_principals and FROM sys.server_principals

Thank you again,

Comment: Instead of creating actual database users you could consider having a single user for the application and then modeling application users in tables where you store users, credentials, roles, permissions, etc. Also, you can consider avoiding making blocking calls from the GUI thread as it will block the interface. Separating GUI from business logic and data access is also a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Cjungel. I thought we separated all three logical models, we have the database with SQL server, the GUI where the user interacts and then the actual code itself, however we are new to this; and this is for school. 

If I understand correctly you are saying to just use one user to login into the server and then create a whole new table called users, depending on that table each user will have permission to the other tables?

Also, there is no way of going forward with the way we are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. WOHOOO!!!

Im adding the code in case someone else needs it.

Now to figure out how to restrict certain tables to each new user....

Thank you,

```
try {

                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";
                    username = UsernametextField.getText().trim();
                    password = PasswordtextField.getText().trim();

                    if (username.equals("")|| password.equals(""))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," name or password is wrong","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(AdminMenu.DATABASE_URL, AdminMenu.UserName, AdminMenu.Password);
                        statement = connection.createStatement();


                        resultSetInt = statement.executeUpdate("CREATE LOGIN "+username+" WITH PASSWORD = '"+password+"'");
                        resultSetInt = statement.executeUpdate("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'"+username+"') CREATE USER ["+username+"] FOR LOGIN ["+username+"] EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'"+username+"'");

                        //("CREATE LOGIN NewAdminName WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCD' GO USE BEPAWI GO IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'NewAdminName') BEGIN CREATE USER [NewAdminName] FOR LOGIN [NewAdminName]  EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'NewAdminName' END;) VALUES('"+username+"', '"+password+"');");

                        String SMessage = "Record added for "+username;

                                           // create dialog ox which is print message
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,SMessage,"Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        //close connection
                        ((java.sql.Connection)connection).close();
                    }

                    }

                catch (SQLException se) 
                {
                    //handle errors for JDBC
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception a) //catch block
                {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```